# Harder Narasimhan polygon

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves

We know for vector bundles on smooth projective curve we have a HN filtration. Let $0=E_0 \leq E_1 ... \leq E_n=E$ be such a filtration of $E$. Then we can construct a convex polygon with lattice point vertices where for each $E_i$ we mark the point $(r_i,d_i)$ corresponding to its rank and degree.

> Given any such convex polygon with lattice point vertices can we produce a vector bundle whose Harder Narasimhan polygon is exactly that one?

Edit : After the counterexample posted in the comments I am refining my polygon. I am starting with a convex polygon in the first quadrant such that origin is a vertex. I also require the slopes to be decreasing (slopes of each edge from the left to right as the HN filtration needs that decreasing slopes criteria.

Now can I say such a polygon comes from a HN filtration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I really understand your question. Here is an example. $(1,0),(2,-1),(4,-2)$. These cannot come from a Harder-Narasimhan filtration since the $\mu$ sequence is $0,-1, -1/2$ and $-1<-1/2$.

Comment: I think I need to refine the question to avoid such counterexamples. I'd probably for the moment concentrate on convex polygons which lie in first quadrant such that origin is one of the vertices (corresponding to the zero subbundle). I'd also want the slopes to be decreasing from left to right as the HN filtration needs that. Then can I say such a polygon comes from a HN filtration?

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.